# git-push errors out with failed to read object

Tags: git, git-push

I have a new repo at github. I am trying to push my local repo to github for the first time. I am getting the following error.

```
$git push -u origin master
fatal: failed to read object 25560dba99aa5e7e94e77cf9b238c7baf5bff137:                   Invalid argument
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:vivek/fii.git'
```

I did have some corrupted objects which I resorted to the last successful commit.
My local git is working fine after restoration but git-push is failing.

```
git fsck
fatal: failed to read object 0f1ebff038a9624485861b5f5b8a2859cbe4b49c: Invalid argument
```

I tired removing the size 0 files from .git/objects but that does not work either.

-thanks

Comment: can you exclude "-u" flag ?

Comment: Without "-u" flag I still get the same error:

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. I deleted the corrupted object from `.git/objects`. Also, I pointed the `.git/refs/heads/master` to the latest working commit. After this command works fine.

```
$git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 113, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (97/97), done.
Writing objects: 100% (98/98), 773.36 KiB, done.
Total 98 (delta 54), reused 0 (delta 0)
```